# True or false output based on a probability

Tags: python, scientific-computing

Is there a standard function for Python which outputs True or False probabilistically based on the input of a random number from 0 to 1?

example of what I mean:

```
def decision(probability):
    ...code goes here...
    return ...True or False...
```

the above example if given an input of, say, 0.7 will return True with a 70% probability and false with a 30% probability

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
import random

def decision(probability):
    return random.random() < probability
```

Comment: Note that `random.random()` generates numbers uniformally in [0, 1).  0 inclusive and 1 exclusive

Answer (score 3):

Given a function `rand` that returns a number between 0 and 1, you can define `decision` like this:

```
bool decision(float probability)
{
   return rand()<probability;
}
```

Assuming that rand() returns a value in the range `[0.0, 1.0)` (so can output a 0.0, will never output a 1.0).

Comment: This question is tagged `python`, so your code sample seems a little out of place.

Comment: @Blindy +1 Thanks for the Pseudo Code ;) I am from a Java background and quite glad I found your snippet - even if the question is tagged Python.

Comment: @Zainodis, heh yea, I find C-like languages to be an almost universal language if used from a really high level!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [PyProbs](https://pypi.org/project/pyprobs/) library. It is very easy to use.

```py
>>> from pyprobs import Probability as pr
>>> 
>>> # You can pass float (i.e. 0.5, 0.157), int (i.e. 1, 0) or str (i.e. '50%', '3/11')
>>> pr.prob(50/100)
False
>>> pr.prob(50/100, num=5)
[False, False, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to generate a random boolean in python with a probability:

```py
from random import randint
n=8 # inverse of probability
rand_bool=randint(0,n*n-1)%n==0
```

so to expand that :

```py
def rand_bool(prob):
    s=str(prob)
    p=s.index('.')
    d=10**(len(s)-p)
    return randint(0,d*d-1)%d<int(s[p+1:])
```

I came up with this myself but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def prob(p):    # takes a probability in %
    a = np.random.randint(1,101) 
    if a <= p:             
        decision = True
    else: decision = False
    return decision
```

Simple function for a boolean return value based on a input probability.

Comment: Looks like you are not quite answering the question that the OP is asking. The OP is asking for a probability of each answer, not true or false as the return.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to amass a lot of data, I would suggest using a map:

```
    from numpy import random as rn
    p = 0.15
    data = rn.random(100)
    final_data = list(map(lambda x: x < p, data))
```

Comment: What does this add that any of the answers of 8 years don't?