# Get a Random Boolean by percentage

Tags: python, random, python-2.7

I'm trying to get a get a random boolean but with a weighted percentage. For instance, I want the user to pass in a percentage (i.e. 60) and the generator will randomly select true 60% of the time.

What I have is this:

```
def reset(percent=50):
    prob = random.randrange(0,100)
    if prob > percent:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is there a better way to do this? This seems inefficient and cumbersome. I don't need it to be perfect since it is just used to simulate data, but I need this to be as fast as possible.

I've searched (Google/SO) and have not found any other questions for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True or false output based on a probability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886987/true-or-false-output-based-on-a-probability)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just return the test:

```
def reset(percent=50):
    return random.randrange(100) < percent
```

because the result of a `<` lower than operator is already a boolean. You do not need to give a starting value either.

Note that you need to use *lower than* if you want `True` to be returned for a given percentage; if `percent = 100` then you want `True` all of the time, e.g. when all values that `randrange()` produces are below the `percent` value.

Comment: I'd also note that in general, it's more normal to accept a float from `0` to `1` - percentages are a useful human concept, but in computing, this will probably mean multiplying stuff up for no reason. A float will give more range in chances allowed, and probably be quicker (just use `random.random()` instead of `randrange()`).

Comment: @Lattyware: Certainly, but if user input is already given in integer values, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: And I'm just gonna go with 'it's monday'

Comment: @rjbez: Is it really? Golly! :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course, I was just saying for the more general case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the relation is backwards, see my answer, and make the change.

Comment: @Gregory: You are right; I never focused on that because I focused instead on simplifying the method, not wether or not it was correct. Updated now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no worries, that's what i figured. Up voted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def reset(percent=50):
    return random.randrange(0, 100) > percent
```

Answer (score 1):

@rjbez You asked for a function which returns *true* in *X* percentage of time. When X == 0% it should always return false. When X == 100% it should always return true. The current accepted answer is now fixed and has the proper relation

```
def reset(percent=50):
    return random.randrange(100) < percent
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I should have added a comment about that. I did figure that out long ago and updated the code but not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [PyProbs](https://pypi.org/project/pyprobs/) library. It is very easy to use.

```py
>>> from PyProbs import Probability as pr
>>> 
>>> # You can pass float (i.e. 0.5, 0.157), int (i.e. 1, 0) or str (i.e. '60%', '3/11')
>>> pr.Prob('50%')
False
>>> pr.Prob('50%', num=5)
[False, False, False, True, False]
```