# Python: How to make a variable true 40% of the time

Tags: python, django, django-views

What would be the best approach for the following...

In a Django I have a view with a variable called '`showItem`' which could be `true` or `false`. I want to set showItem to true **40%** of the time and false **60%** of the time, with options to change these odds later on.

Using Python how should I go about this?

Part of view:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['showItem'] = (odds?????)
        return context
```

Comment: Try `random.randrange(100) > 40` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324472/random-boolean-by-percentage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
num = random.randint(0, 4)
context['showItem'] = True if num <= 1 else False
```

Here I think @Xaranke's answer is better and more flexible.
I also test the performance of `random` and `randint` on my laptop, the former is 10x faster.

Comment: nice import random is perfect.

Comment: He said he wants to change the odds later on.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that orz.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another method:

```
import random

cur_num   = random.random()
threshold = 0.4

# showItem is true 60 % of the time
showItem = cur_num >= threshold
```

If you choose to change the threshold value later, you can just modify the `threshold` variable which is easier than the other methods listed.