# Probability in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, probability

I have an if statement which should be executet to 80-%.

Easy example:

```
x = True # 80% of the time
y = False # 20% of the time
z = # Either x or y 
i = 0
while i < 10:
   if z == True:
     print(True)
   else:
     print(False)
   i = i+1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [True or false output based on a probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886987/true-or-false-output-based-on-a-probability)

Answer (score 0):

The `choices` function from the `random` module accepts weights for the possible outcomes. So you could just use:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(random.choices((True, False), (80, 20))
```

or as `choices` can return a number of values:

```
for i in random.choices((True, False), (80, 20), k=10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.random()` to get a random number between 0 to 1 with a uniform distribution.

so you expect this number to be < 0.8 80% of the times and > 0.8 20% of the times.

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    r = random.random()
    if r < 0.8:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```